# 100 Buttons and only 1 Active

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have one activity and here i have 100 buttons, i want that when i press Button 1 then press another Button the Button 1 should get unpressed.

i know i can make this with

```
  if(Button1.isPressed()) {
        Button2.setPressed(false);
        Button3.setPressed(false);
        Button4.setPressed(false);
        Button5.setPressed(false);
        Button6.setPressed(false);
        Button7.setPressed(false);
        Button8.setPressed(false);
        ......................... }
  else { do nothing }
```

.... **BUT!**

1. it's too much code
2. Coders will kill me or will just laugh on me.

any ideas?
maybe there is a way to unpress the all buttons from the activity?

Comment: You can store the buttons in an array and then unpress them in a loop

Comment: did you add buttons programaticaly or in xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution ever, but you could make an `OnClickListener` like this:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View current = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (current != v && current instanceof Button) {
                ((Button) current).setPressed(false);
            }
        }
        ((Button) v).setPressed(true);
    }
}
```

and attach it to all of your buttons.

Then, whenever a button is clicked, it will iterate over all views that are in the same layout (or actually, view group) as the clicked button, and, for any of those views that are buttons except for the clicked button, it will call `setPressed(false)`.

Note that this only works out of the box if all the buttons are in the same layout. If they are in nested layouts, you will have to adapt it a little.

*Off topic: What do you need 100 buttons for? That's a lot of buttons. You may want to redesign your user interface*

Comment: **1.** i have 2 layouts with buttons and Yes that 100 buttons are in one layout

**2.** should i paste this code in each Button? or i can defin it as a public type and call it from buttons.

**3.** i have a player with a list of 100 sounds when i click on one it changes the music resource, and i want it to be selected till other music resource is clicked.

Comment: **2.** No, create the listener once and then set it on all buttons (`setOnClickListener(listener)`) **3.** I suspected something along those lines. I think you should look into using a `ListView` or `GridView`, it will require a little work to change your code now, but will make it **a lot** cleaner and easier to maintain in the long run. A good rule of thumb is generally: **If it looks ugly, it's probably a bad solution**

Answer (score 1):

Ok so instead of looping through all the buttons on over and over again when one button is pressed, you can just store a variable which stores the button number of the button that was last pressed. Now, when the second button is pressed, disable the button that was pressed earlier, you get its index from the saved variable, enable the button that was pressed and store its index in the variable.

Heres an example pseudo code to give you and idea:

```
int buttonLastPressed = 0;
void onButtonClick(Button buttonPressed){
     if(buttonLastPressed != 0){
        disableButton(buttonLastPressed);
        enableButton(buttonPressed);
        buttonLastPressed = buttonPressed.getIndex()
     }
}
```

Saves you from looping through each and every button to disable it.

Comment: i guess i can't use this because i have 2 groups of buttons, in the first group i have 100 buttons which i want to make them unpress when another is pressed, and the second group i want just to keep them as they are

Answer (score 0):

Define id of button 1 to 100

When press button occurs save it's id in some member variable like previous_pressed

Before updating a previous_pressed value find and unpress previous pressed button like this

Button previous_pressed_button = (Button) findViewById(previous_pressed);

Now you have the previous pressed button, So upress it or whatever.